# Queue Item Pick and Release button

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365

I have to show different alerts when the user clicks on the pick and release button, Is there any parameter that is passed when we click on these buttons and get it on Plugin or any other workaround for this.

If there is kindly suggest.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of a built-in button cannot be modified. You can only hide it by adding a `HideCustomAction` in the `RibbonDiffXml` and replacing it with your own `CustomAction`.

Server side you can block the user adding an activity to the queue by registering a plugin on the `AddToQueue` message. When the desired conditions are met, throwing an exception would block the process of adding a queue item. (Only exception here is the asynchronous plugin step.)